# SSMS 2014 does not display windows correctly

Tags: sql-server, ssms, ssms-2014

I just upgraded 2008 sql server to 2014 and now almost all of my windows look like this:

[image]

I didn't have any problems like that in 2008 R2, but not it is really annoying. Does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: Google for "ssms 2014 high dpi". For example, [here is a tip](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/spaghettidba/2015/10/14/ssms-in-high-dpi-displays-how-to-stop-the-madness/) on how to fix that. Worked for me.

Comment: This looks like a text size issue in Windows, what version of the operating system are you using?

Comment: @PaulAndrew I'm using windows 8.1 64-bit

Comment: Thanks @Nicky, but I think Christian has already hit the nail on the head with high DPI screen resolution link.