# Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, running in high-dpi mode breaks activity window form layouts

Tags: sql-server, ssms

When I try to add a new database in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, the fields are so compressed that I cannot put in any information or see any.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

[image]

I was looking for fields big enough to put information in

Comment: My have you tagged MySQL? That is a competing product...

Comment: SQL Server and MySQL are two totally different products. The first is produced by Microsoft, the second by Oracle. Tag spamming is a very quick way to get your post closed here. Tags have relevance and meaning, and abusing them isn't acceptable. Please use only tags that actually apply to your post. You'll find your experiences here will be much better if you spend some time taking the [tour] and reading the [help] pages to learn how the site works before you begin posting.

Comment: "[compressed fields](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/data-compression/data-compression?view=sql-server-ver16)" is something else entirely - I've retitled this question.

Comment: Anyway, the fix is to run SSMS at 96dpi - which is always does by default (due to its embedded Win32 manifest file), so I'm curious why it _isn't_ running at 96dpi on your machine...

Comment: Probably display scaling. When you go to properties of the shotcut to ssms > compatibility > high DPI settings you can change settings for ssms specifically.

Comment: [SqlServer Management Studio 2016 High DPI issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41551911) and [SSMS 2014 does not display windows correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37705099) seem relevant, although only the first has the answer.

Comment: welcome to SO... haha. sorry about them all. haha. great question (despite mixing up MsSQL and MySQL - boo, hiss... quite understandable... like v. junior devs. constantly confusing java and javascript: u r not the only one bro). I have been meaning to find the time to work this out, and this lot (and you @GuyWith100melons !) have sorted me out. Great. Thanks all points all round !